# Why Does My IP Ask for Login Credentials?

Tags: apache-http-server, ip

I have my website all ready to be tested and served, but when I go to the IP address, I get a login prompt asking for my username and password.

NOTHING I do with this prompt allows me to access my site.

Is there something I am configuring incorrectly in Apache that is causing this?

EDIT: I am using a regular, linksys router with "no-ip".

Comment: Do happen to be behind a consumer router with a stupid port-forwarding setup?  You are probably being prompted for your router authentication credentials.

Comment: @Zoredache Most likely this is the case. I am using no-ip so that I can bypass my ISP's no static ip's for free policy.

Answer (score 1):

That's your router. Your public IP address is the IP address assigned to your router. You need to set up port forwarding on your router, and you probably need to move the administrative interface to another port as well.